# javascript select nested element in bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, nested, append

I've been searching everywhere for answers but can't find the results. I have tried queryselect, queryselectall, getelementbytagname, etc. etc. but again nothing happens. 
what I am trying to do is get the can element nested in the bootstrap 4 carousel. The idea is instead of pic of a can displaying in the browser and then move to the next slide on autoplay which will then show another pic of a can I want to show a 3d-effect of the can rotating in the screen. I have done the rotating of the can by javascript in a different file but now having troubles to fit it in bootstrap 4 carousel.

```
 const clickFn = () => {
          const $bottleSize = getElement('.carousel>.carousel-inner>.carousel-item>.can');
          const $bottle1 = changeBottleSize();
          const $bottle2 = changeBottleSize();
          const $bottle3 = changeBottleSize();
```

here I have tried everything to change the getElement('') like ('.can') or ('.carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item .can') and other stuff.

```
const getElement = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
```

here i change it to querySelectorAll or getElementById like  `const getElement = () => document.getElementById("#can");`, etc. etc.

again no changes. And what I notice is when I have it querySelectorAll console displays a message saying

```
bootstrap-can.html:251 Uncaught TypeError: $can.append is not a function
    at initApp (bootstrap-can.html:251)
    at bootstrap-can.html:254
```

really don't know what I am doing wrong here

CSS

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.bottle:hover {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(350px, 190px, 40px) scale(0.5);
}

.bottle {
    transition: all 0.2s;
    width: 10.125px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(650px, 190px, 40px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(650px, 190px, 40px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(350px, 190px, 40px);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: scale(0.1);
    position: absolute;
}

.bottle0 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 300px;
}

.bottle1 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 500px;
}

.bottle2 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 700px;
}

.bottle>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -180px;
    left: -182px;
    width: 374px;
}

.label {
    -webkit-animation: spin 50s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 50s infinite linear;
    animation: spin 50s infinite linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10.55px;
    height: 679px;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
}

.bottle0 .side {
    background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/BZ8rj2NM/sleve.png");
}


/* .bottle1 .side {
          background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/Fs2RgnN6/passion.png");
        }

        .bottle2 .side {
          background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/zGzJjm40/raspberry.png");
        } */

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
        transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
        transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
        transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}

@mixin makeSide() {}

HTML 


        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <!-- <img class="d-block w-50" src="amor2.png" alt="First slide"> -->
                    <div class="container"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <!-- <img class="d-block w-50" src="amor2.png" alt="Second slide"> -->
                    <div class="container"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <!-- <img class="d-block w-50" src="amor2.png" alt="Third slide"> -->
                    <div class="container"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
JS


    const getElement = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
    const createElement = (tag) => document.createElement(tag);
    // const addBackground1 = document.style['background'] = 'url ("https://i.postimg.cc/BZ8rj2NM/sleve.png")';

    const addSideStyle = ($side, i) => {
        let deg = 3.75 * i;
        let bgPosition = 972 - (i * 10.125);

        $side.style['background-position'] = bgPosition + 'px 0';
        $side.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotateY(' + deg + 'deg) translateZ(154px)';
        $side.style['-moz-transform'] = 'rotateY(' + deg + 'deg) translateZ(154px)';
        $side.style['transform'] = 'rotateY(' + deg + 'deg) translateZ(154px)';
    };

    const createBottle = () => {
        const $bottle = createElement('div');
        $bottle.classList.add('bottle');
        const $bottleLabel = createBottleLabel();

        for (let i = 0; i < 96; i = i + 1){
            let $bottleSide = createBottleSide(i);
            $bottleLabel.append($bottleSide);
        }

        $bottle.append($bottleLabel);

        return $bottle;
    };

    const createBottleLabel = () => {
        const $bottleLabel = createElement('div');
        $bottleLabel.classList.add('label');

        return $bottleLabel;
    }

    const createBottleSide = (i) => {
        const $bottleSide = createElement('div');
        $bottleSide.classList.add('side');
        addSideStyle($bottleSide, i);

        return $bottleSide;
    };

    const changeBottleSize = (clickFn) => {
      const _bottle = createElement('div');
      _bottle.classList.add('bottle');

      _bottle.style['transform'] = 'scale(0.9)';
      return _bottle;
    }

    const clickFn = () => {
      const $bottleSize = getElement('.carousel>.carousel-inner>.carousel-item>.can');
      const $bottle1 = changeBottleSize();
      const $bottle2 = changeBottleSize();
      const $bottle3 = changeBottleSize();

      $bottleSize.style['transform'] = 'scale(0.9)';
      return $bottleSize;
    }

    const initApp = () => {
        const $can = getElement('.carousel>.carousel-inner>.carousel-item>.can');
        const $bottle1 = createBottle();
        const $bottle2 = createBottle();
        const $bottle3 = createBottle();

        [$bottle1, $bottle2, $bottle3].forEach(($bottle, i) => {
          $bottle.classList.add('bottle' + i);
        });

        $can.append($bottle1, $bottle2, $bottle3);  
    };

    initApp();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you using JQuery?

Comment: Yes there's JQuery plugin such as jquery.min.js

Comment: The error is with the variable `$can`, but it doesn't appear anywhere in your code?

Comment: copied the wrong code! back to normal now

Comment: if you `console.log($can);` after this line, what do you get?

Comment: it shows me the whole html file! <div class="can"></div> etc.

Comment: when I click the can element it then displays 3 elements of bottle like <div class="bottle bottle0"></div> and two more elements for bottle1 and bottle2. when I highlight it it shows that the elements are in the browser but just want display the image if that makes sense

Comment: I'm not too familiar with JQuery, but I think the problem is that you're mixing plain JS with JQuery. I think you need to change your `getElement` function to use `$( ".carousel>.carousel-inner>.carousel-item>.can" )`. `append` is JQuery and `document.querySelector` is plain JS. They may not work well together, which is likely why you're getting the `append` is not a function error.